# Import Export Data for India

Tags: data-request, india

I am looking for trade data of India with other countries in the form of Import or Export. Creating a research project in my field.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Import Export data of India period wise (Annually, Monthly) and commodities wise. [Trade Statistics, Government of India](https://commerce.gov.in/trade-statistics/)